# Return given string matching line

Tags: php, file-io, string-matching

I want write function something like this

```
getLine($mySteing){
 .....
}
```

How to get line form file(file.txt) given sting include(matching)?. please help

```
define('COMPANY_FULL_NAME', 'sdfstd') = getLine( "define\(\'COMPANY_FULL_NAME\'\" );
```

**file.txt**

```
define ( 'APP_TITLE', 'Ekdi Inc' ); 
define('COMPANY_NAME', 'WosdfP');
define('COMPANY_FULL_NAME', 'sdfstd');
```

Comment: `getLine($myString){ /*...*/ }` is **not** valid code, `function getLine($myString){ /*...*/ }` **is** valid code

Comment: you want to define then equal ? 
Sorry but your question is not understandable..

Comment: Return given string matching line, translated is : return the line number, where the string was found

Comment: thanks i did some mistake now correct that mistakes

Comment: save it a php and include in your script...easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following function will find all the lines that match your string, and it will echo the line number, as $i

```
    function getLine($string)
    {

    $file = fopen("fle.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
    $i = 0;
    while(!feof($file))
      {
       $i++;
       $line = fgets($file);
       $pos = strpos($line, $string);
       if( $pos !== false )echo $i.'<br/>';
      }
    fclose($file);

    }
```

by the way, don't escape characters, don't use \ within the string parameter, as you did in yur code

read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: i not pass complete line of string in to the method. so your function check ($line == $string) complete line. when i send to 'APP_TITLE' your method that doesn't rerun define ( 'APP_TITLE', 'Ekdi Inc' ); line